# How to automate 'wrapperclass' objects

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

We're trying to automate one POS application using QTP/UFT.

But when we try to identify the objects, it gets recognized as just 'window' and it's properties are look to be wrapped. i.e., we could see something like 'HwndWrapperClass....'.

Please confirm how to overcome this issue in QTP/UFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search seems to show that `HwndWrapperClass` is used in WPF. Try using UFT with the WPF add-in selected.

Also in the **Record and Run Settings** dialog, under the *Windows Applications* tab make sure to add your application to the list of applications (and launch the application after UFT is opened).